# How to Retrieve the Last Reactable Object

Tags: r, reactable

I am currently working with `reactable` in R and I am trying to find a way to retrieve the last `reactable` object, similar to how `ggplot2::last_plot()` is used to get the last plot object. How can I achieve this?

```
library(reactable)
reactable(iris)
```

Now I want to retrieve the last `reactable` object.
Something like `last_reactable()` (doesn't exist).

Comment: Maybe, the simple `(X = reactable(iris))`  is a workaround.

Comment: If your're in RStudio and work with projects, try search in the history pane. Maybe you can retrieve the command and run it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work on a session base:

- hook a tracer to the desired function (here: `reactable`) so that the quoted code of the `tracer` argument executes on each call to `reactable`:

```
trace(what = reactable, tracer = quote(assign('.last_reactable_args',
                                         as.list(match.call()[-1]),
                                         envir = .GlobalEnv
                                  )))
```

Above code grabs the arguments `reactable` was called with and stores it as a hidden list in the global environment.

- write a function `last_table` which calls `reactable` with this list (= the latest arguments):

```
last_reactable <- \() do.call(reactable, .last_reactable_args)
```

`last_reactable` now replays the latest `reactable` call.

Answer (score -1):

Just assign it to a variable and use it.

```
last_reactable <- reactable(iris)
last_reactable
```

If the variable is empty maybe there's not variable called that way.